# SQLServer CLR Trigger

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, triggers, sqlclr, sql-server-2014

I cannot for the life of me find anything that pertains to the scenario I'm in. And to preface, I'm relatively new to SQL CLR Triggers in general. The scenario I'm in has a CLR Trigger assembly that I've created in my SQL Server, where the .NET code itself does some business logic based on an inserted or updated record to a single database table. Essentially, the .NET code pulls that data from the table to do its work, then updates the same table.

In all, I've got this working just fine, as long as the SQL Server and the application with the .NET code in question resides on the same machine. I've set up a development environment for our real world customers with a SQL Server residing on one machine, and the application that employs the SQL Server on a different machine, trying to mimic the distributed environment. However, when the trigger 'fires' in SQL Server, how does the application use that trigger when it is on another machine?

Here is what I think I know, or rather questions so that I verify I'm thinking about it correctly.

Our clients use a distributed environment where the SQL Server used by one or more of our applications can use from remote machines. (Already know about starvation on triggers that take too long, and I've got that handled). Does a CLR Trigger need to be employed to a 'specific' server or (for a SQL Server Project) can that server by determined dynamically?

Does the SqlContext know the contextual relationship with the SQL Server machine? Or is that determined in the VS project file and is 'specifically' indicated? Can it be changed or does the CREATE ASSEMBLY always keep the defined value based on the compile it is created against?

I know that the trigger is created in SQL Server, and the same trigger reference is set up in the .NET code ([SqlTrigger(Name="aTrigger", etc...). In other words, how does the remote application know that a trigger set up in SQL Server has fired? Does the SqlContext only know a trigger has fired if the application itself calls into the SQL Server? If so, what happens when an insert/update occurs in the SQL Management Studio?

Ok, enough with the questions. I could go on a while with them, so let's see if anything makes sense to anyone first. I might be in over my head with this stuff. Thanks for any advice given.

Comment: What kind of business logic is your trigger doing in .NET code that couldn't be done in T-SQL?

Comment: It calls into a piece of our .NET code that itself calls into a WCF service. Because of the WCF call, I can't do anything in T-SQL, at least as far as my limited knowledge and google have told me. In any case, this part has been tested with the SQL Server and is not at issue here. Now it's just down to figuring out how to detect that a trigger has gone off.

Comment: The trigger could log something, somewhere, and something else could monitor that somewhere for changes. That table could have a normal trigger, for example, or query notifications, or the trigger could make use of service broker, etc. etc.

Comment: If I had to poll 'somewhere' for changes, then I could just poll the particular table in the database. Our outfit wanted to try to implement this without polling (though I have a feeling this is where it'll end up anyhow). I assume you mean the SQL Server Service Broker, I looked into that but it seemed to imply that it brokered communications between SQL Servers. I'll take another look at that presently. It's just possible this can't be done at all, which is ok, at least that is progress (I've been working on this for several days without much success).

Comment: No, Service Broker is not just for "between SQL Servers"...

Comment: Don't believe this will work for my purposes, if I'm going to monitor a queue I can just poll the database table for what I need instead. I'm chalking this one up to "can't be done in this implementation", since I definitely need the trigger to activate the .NET code and that just isn't happening in the dynamic distributed environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working without the service broker. Because my understanding of how CLR Triggers worked was rather limited, I didn't realize that the SQL Assemblies I created were the actual ones that would run, thanks to logging I was able to determine that I was thinking about this the wrong way. Once I understood this concept, the things I was expecting to be there (was assuming it was running in my .NET code and not as an SQL assembly) were not, so I just had to approach it differently. Once I worked out the details of getting things aligned from the context of the SQL running the assemblies, everything fell into place and bang, it worked. Consider this topic closed. Thanks once again for the help, it was appreciated.